# ¿como obtener todos los jobs en scripts separados sql server ssis?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Cuando es necesario generar los scripts de drop y create de los jobs en SQL Server de forma separada, no es posible a través del Management Studio de SQL Server, solo se puede ir uno a uno para hacer esto...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema de esto es cuando se tienen muchos jobs, pasa a ser un trabajo de nunca terminar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución a este problema es la siguiente:

Me basaré en la solución propuesta por Thomas Lane (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/70475/), en donde mediante un task script en ssis se pueden generar de manera independiente todos los script de un servidor.

1) Necesitamos tener las siguientes variables declaradas en el proyecto:

[image: declaracion de variables]

2)Agregamos un task script en donde pasaremos las variables declaradas en la parte de ReadOnlyVariables:

[image: readOnlyVariaves]

3)Editamos el script en C#, en donde necesitamos agregar las siguientes referencias al proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para agregar las referencias, estas tienen que ser buscadas en *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies* y agregar las ddls correspondientes.

Una vez echo, podremos agremar los siguientes import al proyecto:
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

Luego el método Main(), tiene que tener el siguiente código:

```
public void Main()
        {
            string strFolder = @Dts.Variables["FilePath"].Value.ToString();
            StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
            ScriptingOptions so = new ScriptingOptions();
            so.IncludeDatabaseContext = true;
            string filename = "";

            //en caso de iniciar seison con cuenta de windows en sql, utilizamos esta parte...
            /*
            ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection();
            conn.LoginSecure = true;
            conn.ServerInstance = Dts.Variables["ServerName"].Value.ToString();
            */


            // si utiliamos cuenta de usuario en sql server utilizamos lo siguiente:
            ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection();
            conn.LoginSecure = false;
            conn.Login = Dts.Variables["UserName"].Value.ToString();
            conn.Password = Dts.Variables["Password"].Value.ToString();
            conn.ServerInstance = Dts.Variables["ServerName"].Value.ToString();
            Server srv = new Server(conn);



            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(strFolder))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strFolder);
            }

            string script = "";
            string strDrop = "";
            string JobName;
            //Loop over all the jobs
            foreach (Job J in srv.JobServer.Jobs)
            {
                //Output name in the console
                Console.WriteLine(J.Name.ToString());
                JobName = J.Name.ToString();
                sc = J.Script(so);
                strDrop = "USE [MSDB] " + (char)13 + (char)10;
                strDrop = strDrop + "IF  EXISTS (SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view WHERE name = N'";
                strDrop = strDrop + J.Name.ToString() + "')";
                strDrop = strDrop + (char)13 + (char)10;
                strDrop = strDrop + " EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'" + J.Name.ToString();
                strDrop = strDrop + "', @delete_unused_schedule=1";
                strDrop = strDrop + (char)13 + (char)10 + "GO";
                strDrop = strDrop + (char)13 + (char)10;
                //Get all the text for the job
                foreach (string s in sc)
                {
                    script += s;
                }
                script = strDrop + script;
                //Generate the file
                filename = JobName + ".sql";
                filename = Regex.Replace(filename, @"[\/:?'=|]", "");
                if (strFolder.Substring(strFolder.Length - 1, 1) == @"\")
                {
                    filename = strFolder + filename;
                }
                else
                {
                    filename = strFolder + @"\" + filename;
                }
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename);
                tw.Write(script);
                tw.Close();
                //Make the string blank again
                script = "";
                strDrop = "";
            }


            // TODO: Add your code here

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Luego guardamos y ejecutamos el codigo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisamos la path, y vemos los script generados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Sigue estos pasos:

1. Ve a la Base de datos donde necesitas obtener todos los scripts de los jobs.
2. Presiona F7.
3. Buscas los jobs y seleccionas los que necesitas.
4. Click derecho y **CREATE To >> Script Job as...**